# Ember model not updated when new model is added to it's hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**Models**
A User has many Companies (one to many relationship). Ember models:

```
// User model
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    companies: DS.hasMany("company", {async: true})
});

App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo("user")
});
```

**Problem**
When I create a new company model, define its user property and save() it, the User's companies property does not update until I refresh the page. Example:

```
var user = this.get("controllers.application").get("model"); // Get user
company.set('user', user); // Set user to current user  
company.save(); // Call POST HTTP verb to update db model
```

However, as a work around, i can explicitly push the new Company model into the users list of companies, to see the new company straight away. I do not call save() after i do this. But is this step necessary?

```
user.get("companies").pushObject(company); // Add company to users list of companies
```

**App Details**
    - Using Ember RESTAdapter
    - Flask Server on backend with Flask-SQLAlchemy
    - Using Flask-Restless

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try what you have with the `user` relationship marked as `async` too? I don't think that's your issue, but I've seen stranger things from Ember-Data relationships.

Comment: Nope, not that. Thanks though. I'm going to try set the model for the 'My Companies' route as companies from store, where user = user, as opposed to setting currently logged in user as the model.

Comment: I haven't used Ember-Data in a very long time, so I'm going to see if somebody with more experience can answer this question first. If not, I might take a stab at it when I get off of work. But either way, a JSBin reproducing the issue would help us all. (It might even help you track down the source of the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was what model I was assigning to this route. I was previously assigning the logged in User as the model, and accessing their list of companies like:

```
App.MyCompaniesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find("user", 1); // ID is 1 for example
    }
});
```

Where as I should have been setting the model for this route as all the companies in the store that have the same user as the currently logged in User, e.g.:

```
model: function(){
    this.store.filter("company", function(company){
        return company.get("user") == currentUser; // Current user model
    });
}
```

Thanks!